# Angular2 get ActivatedRoute url

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I want to get the url which comes from this:

`this.router.navigate(./somepath, { relativeTo: this.route })`

`this.route` is of the type `ActivatedRoute`.

I tried `url: string = route.snapshot.url.join('');` but this gives an empty string.

Answer (score 26):

You can use the activated route to get active URL.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
 constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(activatedRoute.snapshot['_routerState'].url); 
}
```

Comment: `(<RouterStateSnapshot>activatedRoute['_routerState']).url`, if you like to type it.

Comment: It's a kind of hack, isn't it? `_routerState` property is private for some reason probabely. I had problem to get full url from lazy loaded module, and it work job for me.

Comment: you can do it without using _routerState: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57254953/1990451

Answer (score 25):

This should help:

```
constructor(router: Router) {
  const url = router.url;
}
```

Comment: This approach is synchronous and not asynchronous, which might mean that for any router changes in the URL your app might not be updated correctly

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem, I wanted to store the string from the current url! There were many solution but none helped me, then I found how to do this in pure Js, so I try the same line of code in angular, then it worked!!

```
window.location.href
```

but what really helped me was this:

```
window.location.pathname;
```

for example:

```
currentRout: string;

ngOnInit() {
this.currentRout = window.location.href;
console.log(this.currentRout);
}
```

Comment: This look like a workaround more than the correct way to do it

Answer (score 7):

For me the following works:

```js
const url = '/' + this.route.pathFromRoot
  .map(route => route.snapshot.url)
  .filter(urlSegments => !!urlSegments[0])
  .map(([urlSegment]) => urlSegment.path)
  .join('/');
```

This manually traverses through all parent routes and collects the result URL.

No hacks, no use of private properties. Works for lazy loaded modules.

Answer (score 6):

Where are you trying to use it?

Since you're using route, which get injected in the constructor, you can't use route directly in the property init. So you need to do it in or after the constructor have been called. So something like this should work:

```
export class Test {
    url: string
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.url = this.route.snapshot.url.join('');
    }
}
```

The official documentation shows a different way to get the current url: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html
which is async, so maybe it's not what you're after. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm able to get the current page URL using the following code snippet

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}

const url = this.activatedRoute['_routerState'].snapshot.url;
```

Comment: This ought to be the top answer. Uses the angular Router, does the job. announced on the tin.

Comment: In my code I would prefer to use this solution but the problem is that I am getting the following error despite the property exist:  "Property '_routerState' does not exist on type 'ActivatedRoute' ". This means it won't compile. (with Angular 8)

Answer (score 3):

I used the solution from Phillip Patton, but the `flat()` function is not supported in IE/Edge, so the following is an alternative:

```js
'/' + this.route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.snapshot.url)
  .reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])
  .map(urlSegment => urlSegment.path)
  .join('/');
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it like this:

```
import { filter, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

constructor(
  private router: Router
) {
  this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof ChildActivationEnd),
    take(1),
  ).subscribe(event=>{
    const url = event.snapshot['_routerState'].url;
    console.log('url', url);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it without being quite as hacky. I used lodash for flattening the array also.

```
_.flatten(this.route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.snapshot.url)).join('/')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  constructor(
      readonly location: Location
  )
```

then

```
this.location.path()
```

this will get the url

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me and takes into account the full path from root.

Adding the `flat()` function where the nested array is returned helped with the subsequent map function. It just had to deal with flat array instead of somehow dereferencing a nested array in the 2nd map call.

```js
'/' + route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.snapshot.url)
  .flat()
  .map(urlSegment => urlSegment.path)
  .join('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @smnbbrv mentioned, you can now do it a little easier.

```
route.pathFromRoot.flatMap(r => r.snapshot.url).map(r => r.path).join('/');
```

At least, in Angular 14, route.snapshot.url returns an array. Flatmap ignores the empty arrays, so they don't need to be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the parameter, you need to subscribe to the url variable of the ActivatedRoute.

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe((url: UrlSegment[]) => {
        console.log(url[0].path);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to subscribe you can check the URL directly using:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.url[0].path);
}
```