# Get the URL of a Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get `this._my.dialog = location.pathname.replace('/', '');` in Angular8 , but this does not always return the url, even if I include it in `ngOnInit()`.

Especially, when:

- changing the URL
- loading for the first time

app.component.html

```
  <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
  <div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-myAppForGettingTheURL></app-myAppForGettingTheURL>
  </div>
```

How do I do it correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153045/angular2-get-activatedroute-url

Comment: @altu, `this._activatedRoute.snapshot['_routerState'].url`, doesnt display anything, it's empty. Maybe because of `app-myAppForGettingTheURL` is used everywhere (inside app.compponent.html)

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute           
  `const url: Observable<string> = route.url.pipe(map(segments => segments.join('')));`

Comment: @altu, the string is alwasys empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete working demo is found here.. [StackBlitzLink](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apnav7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html)

You need to subscribe router events in root component of your project. same like this.

```
 this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) this.url = this.router.url
 });
```

Just change url from home to about and see routed url in app.component.

Comment: Ok, but when I change the Url `<a [routerLink]=`, somewhere in `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` it doesn't work

Comment: see updated answer in StackBlitz link, I have added `<a [routerLink]="['/about']">about</a>`

Comment: ok, I get the url over a foreach `<a [routerLink]="url"`, I got problems, when escaping that variable, like `<a [routerLink]="['/{{url}}']"`, parse error

Comment: Check again updated StackBlitz link in above link. for that you need to use like this `<a routerLink={{path}}>About</a>`

Comment: Your link does not open. Share your complete stackblitz link.

Comment: in your stackblitz link , in homeComponent.html change a tag to this.. `<a [routerLink]="url" class="btn btn-outline-primary">click</a>`

Comment: and you must have your `subTopics` url path set to `app-routing.module.ts` file. otherwise, `router not found error occurs`.

Comment: I have updated stackblitz link for the same too. have a look here...  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apnav7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html